# Como saber no html do Django, se a view tá com instance preenchido?

Tags: python, django

Estou iniciando meus estudos no Django, em um CRUD, eu criei um único form que gostaria de utilizar tanto pra criação quanto para alteração.

Gostaria de alterar o texto do button dependendo da função a ser designada ao form. No Laravel eu verificava se o objeto passado estava vazio para saber se é criação ou alteração.

No django fiz assim, no views.py passei pelo render o valor do submit

```
return render(request, 'form.html', {'form':form, 'btn_submit': 'Cadastrar'})
```

e

```
return render(request, 'form.html', {'form':form, 'btn_submit': 'Alterar'})
```

No html simplesmente usei o valor com uma interpolação

```
<!-- form.html -->
<input type="submit" value="{{ btn_submit }}">
```

Agradeceria a ajuda, se puderem me indicar melhores métodos ou boas práticas, seria muito útil no meu aprendizado. Obrigado.

Comment: o seu form vai ser literalmente o mesmo nos dois templates? no template de alteração você não vai passar o objeto, por exemplo?

Comment: @MuriloSitonio Sim, o mesmo form pra ambos. Quando se trata de alteração, é passado o objeto já preenchido.